# Trigger click based on changes in specific div classes - needs to loop

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my function, when the user changes something inside the `.ap-create-story-panel-wrap` div, and then clicks outside that specific div, trigger a button click.

As the selector for the container variable, I am using the data-panel attribute. This works for the first one, but I need it to work for all the other `.ap-create-story-panel-wrap` divs as well.

I tried with a loop, with the data attribute as a selector, but nothing worked.

```js
$('.ap-create-story-panel-wrap[data-panel="basicinfopanel"]').change(function() {
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $('.ap-create-story-panel-wrap[data-panel="basicinfopanel"]');

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(".btn-basicinfopanel").trigger("click");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ap-create-story-panel-wrap" data-panel="infopanel">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<a class="btn-basicinfopanel" data-target="certificatepanel">Save/Next</a>

<div class="ap-create-story-panel-wrap" data-panel="certifypanel">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<a class="btn-certifypanel" data-target="certifypanel">Save/Next</a>

<div class="ap-create-story-panel-wrap" data-panel="photopanel">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<a class="btn-photopanel" data-target="photopanel">Save/Next</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if i understood the problem correctly. I'll just try to re phrase the problem statement the way i understood (my answer will be for that case).

**Problem:** there are multiple `div`s with an input each inside them. Any change to the `value` of `input` should trigger a `click` on the `button` defined by the parent `div`.

**Solution:** 
Target the `input` in each `div.ap-create-story-panel-wrap`

```
$('div.ap-create-story-panel-wrap input')
```

Assuming that you'd also want the `click` event to trigger also when the user hits `TAB` to move to next `input`, listen for change

```
.on('change', function() {});
```

Now, inside callback function, get the target btn from parent `div`

```
let tgt = $(this).closest('div.ap-create-story-panel-wrap').data('panel');
let bCls = '.btn-'+tgt;   // btn class
```

Now trigger click

```
$(bCls).trigger('click');
```

So the entire thing becomes:

```
$('div.ap-create-story-panel-wrap input').on('change', function() {
    let tgt = $(this).closest('div.ap-create-story-panel-wrap').data('panel');
    let bCls = '.btn-'+tgt;   // btn class
    $(bCls).trigger('click');
});
```

Let me know if you don't wish to trigger click on losing the focus from an input an only if a mouse click is made after a change (i couldn't think of a reason).

In any case, I wouldn't attach a persistent `click` event to `document` directly. I'd rather detach the event at the end of function like suggested in one of the answers above or add/update `data-old` on `input`s right after the `click` triggers and do a comparison with actual value when mouse click happens on the `document`

**UPDATE:**

Based on the comment. See inline comments for explanation (esp., note the change in first line on `HTML` snippet).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Record original value of each input. We will use it to compare with actual value later
    $('div.ap-create-story-panel-wrap input').each(function() {
        $(this).data('old', $(this).val());
    });

    // Listen to mouse click anywhere except input
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        // Check which input value changed
        $('div.ap-create-story-panel-wrap input').each(function() {
            let ov = $(this).data('old');
            let nv = $(this).val();
            
            if(nv != ov) {
                console.log('previous value: ',ov || "empty field");
                console.log('present value: ',nv || "empty field");
                
                // Trigger click on its btn
                let tgt = $(this).closest('div.ap-create-story-panel-wrap').data('panel');
                
                console.log('change detected in ', tgt);
                
                let bCls = '.btn-'+tgt;   // btn class
                $(bCls).trigger('click');

                // Update data-old to new value to prepare for any further change detection
                $(this).data('old', $(this).val());
            }
        });
    });
    
    $('div.ap-create-story-panel-wrap').on('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    });

    // Added only for demo, not needed in actual code
    $('a').on('click', function() {
        console.log('Target on clicked button: ', $(this).data('target'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- P.S: I changed data-panel="infopanel" to data-panel="basicinfopanel" to make it consistent with other divs -->
<div class="ap-create-story-panel-wrap" data-panel="basicinfopanel">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<a class="btn-basicinfopanel" data-target="certificatepanel">Save/Next</a>

<div class="ap-create-story-panel-wrap" data-panel="certifypanel">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<a class="btn-certifypanel" data-target="certifypanel">Save/Next</a>

<div class="ap-create-story-panel-wrap" data-panel="photopanel">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<a class="btn-photopanel" data-target="photopanel">Save/Next</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. But basically yes, it's the other way around. I'm trying to "fake" an autosave.

I would like to trigger the button IF the user has made a change in that specific div, and then clicks outside of that div. Sorry for not being specific enough in my initial post!

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent element of the input that was changed and look at the data-panel attribute to figure out which button to trigger the click on.

```
$('.ap-create-story-panel-wrap').change(function(e) {
  var container = $(e.target).parent();
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var dataPanelName = container.attr("data-panel");
    $(".btn-" + dataPanelName).trigger("click");
  });
});
```

NOTE: This will create an event handler on the document which will persist there even after triggering the click.  So you may want to remove the listener after the first time it is triggered.

It is also probably better not to trigger a button to do something, but call whichever javascript directly.

Comment: Thanks Bradley! So would the change function be on the input then? So, 

$('.ap-create-story-panel-wrap input').change(function(e) {

Instead of 

$('.ap-create-story-panel-wrap').change(function(e) {

Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

Could you try using || instead of &&

Comment: Hi, Eeswar! Can you edit your answer to explain why you think this would work?